# Problem in Hyperbolic expansion

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, limits, trigonometry, hypergeometric-function

I have a given hyperbolic function $$\sigma = \sec h ^2 \Big( \frac{1}{kT} (P \sigma + Q B)\Big)$$

Where $ \frac{1}{kT}$ , P and Q are constant. I want to find  the partial  derivation of $\sigma$ with respect  to B. $\sigma$ and B are the function of B.

What I have got is  that,

$$\frac{\partial \sigma}{ \partial B}  = \frac{ \frac{1}{kT}  CQ \Big(  \sec h ^2 \Big(  \frac{1}{kT}  (P \sigma + Q B)\Big)\Big)}{1 -  \frac{1}{kT} P \Big(  \sec h ^2 \Big(  \frac{1}{kT}  (P \sigma + Q B)\Big)}  $$

I want to find out  that how the  series would be  when $T$ tends to zero  and tends to  infinite. To do that, I think i need series expansion. I'm stuck in this. How to  proceed with the hyperbolic series?

Comment: Do you mean $sech^2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help:

$sech(x)
=\dfrac1{\cosh(x)}
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
sech^2(x)
&=\dfrac1{\cosh^2(x)}\\
&=\dfrac{2}{\cosh(2x)+1}\\
&=\dfrac{2}{(e^{2x}+e^{-2x})/2+1}\\
&=\dfrac{4}{e^{2x}+e^{-2x}+2}\\
\end{array}
$

If $x$ is large,
this is about
$4e^{-2x}$;
if $x$ is small,
this is about

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{4}{e^{2x}+e^{-2x}+2}
&\approx \dfrac{4}{1+2x+2x^2-(1-2x+2x^2)+2}\\
&= \dfrac{4}{4x+2}\\
&= \dfrac{2}{2x+1}\\
&\approx 2(1-2x)\\
&=2-4x\\
\end{array}
$